# Integration using the scaling and squaring approach instead of Euler's method

Tags: python, integration

I'm trying to implement, in Python, the scaling and squaring approach for integration as described in Moler and Van Loan, 2003; Arsigny et al., 2006b,a. The approach basically states that If the number of time steps is a power of two, then the solution can be determined by a scaling and squaring approach. An illustration of the method can be seen in page 3 of the attached paper https://ufile.io/8xdx7.

P.S: It's not homework or something. I'm just trying to optimise my already functional code who uses Euler's method but is is slow.

```
shape = image.shape
dx = np.random.normal(0, 10, shape)
dy = np.random.normal(0, 1, shape)

dx = gaussian_filter(dx, 10)
dy = gaussian_filter(dy, 10)
# dx = gaussian_filter((random_state.rand(*shape) * 2 - 1), sigma, mode="constant", cval=0) * alpha
# dy = gaussian_filter((random_state.rand(*shape) * 2 - 1), sigma, mode="constant", cval=0) * alpha
han_window_1 = np.hanning(shape[0])
han_window_2 = np.hanning(shape[1])

for i in range(0, shape[1]):
dy[:,i] = dy[:,i] * han_window_1
for i in range(0, shape[0]):
dx[i,:] = dx[i,:] * han_window_2

# here I want to integrate dx and dy using the aforementioned method instead of Euler's method.
```

Comment: Do you mean to say you have *no* idea how to implement it, and are asking for an implementation?

Comment: Basically, at this point, yes.